# How can I wait until a component is shown in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a component (`JPanel`) inside a `Window`.
I always get `false` when calling `panel.isShowing()`,
when calling from a `windowGainedFocus()` event (when the parent window gets focus).

I assume that when the `windowGainedFocus()` event is called, the painting of the `JPanel` within this `Window` had not been finished yet.

I was trying to place that call `isShowing()` on the `paint()` method of this `Window`,
but I always get `isShowing()` = `false`.

Is there a way I could get an event when the `JPanel` is fully shown on screen and the `isShowing()` method will return true ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You should probably best approach this with a hierarchy listener on the panel itself:

```
panel.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
    public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
        if ((HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED & e.getChangeFlags()) !=0 
             && panel.isShowing()) {
          //do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an event but have some specific code that needs to be run after your component has been drawn, you can override `addNotify()`, which gets called to make the component displayable. Example:

```
public void addNotify()
{
    super.addNotify();
    // at this point component has been displayed
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You component will be fully displayed after you receive WindowListener.windowActivated.  You will also run into timing problems and race conditions trying to assign focus before the windowActivated event.